# The C*-envelope of the algebra of continuous functions on a compact topological space is commutative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

In my research in operator theory, specifically in C* algebras and enveloping, I came across this strange footnote in a text (locally published in non English where I study) which states the following:

> Suppose we have X a compact topological space, now suppose we have A, a sub-algebra of the algebra of continuous functions $ C(X) $ and we know A contains 1 (the identity) and that A separates points, in this case we know A is an operator algebra, and we also know the C*-enveloping $ C_{e}^{*}(A) $ is commutative and that there exists a topological space F such that $ C_{e}^{*}(A) \simeq C(F)  $.

OK, I'll admit I am not an expert on enveloping of C* algebras, but this seems really strange to me non the less as it is said as if it is an elementary result but still it is beyond my reach, why is $ C_{e}^{*}(A) $ necessarily commutative and why do we must have $ C_{e}^{*}(A) \simeq C(F)  $, I do not even know what the topological space F is nor do I have any idea how to begin to construct it. Can someone please help me by explaining this strange remark I came across? It seems like valuable information to know but I cannot find it anywhere or understand it. I thank all helpers.

Comment: Well A is by definition contained in a commutative Cstar algebra B, so the enveloping Cstar algebra must be contained in B

Comment: And then once you define E to be the envelope, E is a commutative unital Cstar algebra, hence it's of the form C(K) -- in fact K is the Gelfand spectrum of E

Comment: You may or may not wish to update the "location" field in your profile, btw.

Comment: @YemonChoi thank you this makes it better so in terms of my notation F is the Gelfand spectrum of the envelope as a topological space so is there a way to simplify it even further?

Comment: With a lot of these constructions, any "construction" is usually indirect and not very good at giving a concrete picture. On the other hand, for particular examples it is often possible to guess what F should be, and then check using the definition that this works

Comment: @YemonChoi so would you say in this case I can simplify it further? Could you please give a simplified F in this case?

Comment: No I am not saying that. I am saying that if you had a particular example of an A which you "saw in the wild", you could guess what F should be. For related concepts in classical function theory, look up the words "Shilov boundary".

Comment: At this stage it seems that it would be best for you to do some more reading on the subject - I feel like I've tried to answer, to the best of my abiility right now, the question in your post "Can someone please help me by explaining this strange remark I came across?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What they are aiming at is the following result:

Let $A \subset C(X)$ be a uniform algebra. Then there exists a unique compact set $F \subset X$, known as the Shilov boundary w.r.t. to $A$, such that every function in $A$ achieves its maximum modulus on $F$. Moreover,
$$
C_e^*(A) \cong C(F).
$$
See chapter 16 in Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras by Vern Paulsen for a proof of this result.

Comment: Thanks - I had a vague memory that this is the result, but couldn't remember it precisely off the top of my head